# The trace as an integral over a sphere

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$ and let $\langle \, \cdot\, , \,\cdot\, \rangle$ be an inner product on $V$. We can define a linear functional on the space of endomorphisms of $V$ by
$$
\alpha(A) := \int_{S^{n-1}} \langle Av, v \rangle d\mu,
$$
where $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere defined by the inner product and $d\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $S^{n-1}$. This functional is actually a multiple of the trace. Here's a nasty proof of this:

Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$. Given $v \in V$ we write $v = v_1 e_1 + \cdots + v_n e_n$, so $v \in S^{n-1}$ if and only if $\sum |v_i|^2 = 1$. We now write
$$
Av 
= \sum_{j=1}^n v_j \, A e_j
= \sum_{j,k=1}^n v_j \, a_{jk} e_k
$$
so that
$$
\langle Av ,v \rangle
= \sum_{j,k} a_{jk} \, v_jv_k.
$$
It's now classically known that $\int_{S^{n-1}} v_j v_k d\mu = c \, \delta_{jk}$ for some constant $c$ that's not terribly important here (and depends on the normalization of $\mu$ anyway), so we get
$$
\alpha(A) 
= \int_{S^{n-1}} \langle Av, v \rangle d\mu
= c \operatorname{tr}(A).
$$
**Question** Is there not a better way of doing this? That is, is there not some way of seeing that $\alpha = c \operatorname{tr}$ for some nonzero $c$ without breaking out the local coordinates? This basically comes down to showing that $\alpha(AB) = \alpha(BA)$ for any $A,B \in \operatorname{End} V$, but I can't see how to show that (or equivalently that $\alpha$ vanishes on the commutator) without going through the same calculations as above.

Comment: I asked a similar question a long time ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62358/integral-around-unit-sphere-of-inner-product

Comment: see also (http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=159328)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By its definition, your functional $\alpha$ is invariant under conjugation by $k\in O(n,\mathbb R)$, that is, $\alpha(kAk^{-1})=\alpha(A)$. The representation space of $n$-by-$n$ matrices, for the orthogonal group, is the tensor product of the standard repn (irreducible) with its contragredient. In the tensor product of an irred with its contragredient, there is a unique copy of the trivial repn, quite generally. Thus, up to scalar multiples, there's nothing other than trace.