# Integral is linear to matrices

Tags: integration, symmetry

This is a continuum to this question which I seem to not understand the solution.

[Integral around unit sphere of inner product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62358/)

I don't get how the diagonal is done, I get that (for example, for $n=3$ that)
$$\iiint_B \langle Av, v \rangle dxdydz = \iiint_B a_{11} x_1^2 + a_{22} x_2^2 + a_{33} x_3^2 dx_1dx_2 dx_3 =$$
$$ = (a_{11} + a_{22} + a_{33}) \iint_B x_1^2dx_1dx_2dx_3$$
Which according to the solution is just $\frac{1}{3} Tr(A) \cdot Area(B)$

The part I fail to see is just how is $$\iiint_Bx_1^2dx_1dx_2dx_2=\frac{1}{3}Area(B)$$

Comment: My intuition is that this is due to the fact you are integrating over the unit sphere, so for any point $p$ on the sphere, there is an antipodal point, $-p$ which "cancels" the contribution of the point $p$ to your integral.

Comment: Yes, that part I get, I edited the question to sign the part I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry,
$$\iiint_B x_1^2\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3
=\iiint_B x_2^2\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3
=\iiint_B x_3^2\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3
$$
so
that
\begin{align}
\iiint_B(a_{11}x_1^2+a_{22}x_2^2+a_{33}x_3^2)\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3
&=(a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33})\iiint_B x_1^2\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\\
&=\frac{a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}}3\iiint_B(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\\
&=\frac{\text{Tr}(A)}3\iiint_B(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3.
\end{align}
Now we can evaluate
$$\iiint_B(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3$$
by spherical polars...

Comment: Yes, for $n=3$ and $n=2$ I can do it, however the solution seems to be for any $n \in \mathbb N$, which is a bit unclear because I can't evaluate for every $n$ while it seemed immediate for the author, how do we do it?

Comment: Is $$\int_{B_n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 = Vol(B_n)$$
because it seems like it.

Comment: @RabMakh That's not true for $n=1$. I get $(n/3)\text{Vol}(B_n)$ (spherical polars).