# Laplacian in terms of integral of Hessian over unit sphere

Tags: laplacian, hessian-matrix

Let $u \in C^2$. Somehow I tend to believe that the following identity
$$
\int_{\partial B_1 (x)} \big\langle (\nabla^2 u) (x) y, y \big\rangle d\sigma_y = C \Delta u(x)
$$
holds for some constant $C>0$ depending on $|\partial B_1|$. Here $(\nabla^2 u) (x)$ is the Hessian matrix of $u$ evaluated at $x$. This could depend on the fact that Laplacian is the trace of the Hessian. However, is the above identity true?

Answer (score 1):

This is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62358/integral-around-unit-sphere-of-inner-product),  just substitute $M\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with the Hessian of $u$ at $x$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need :).